# Into trait implemented for arbitrary types in Rust

Tags: rust, containers

How can I implement `Into` trait for arbitrary types, or receive same functionality in whatever way?

For example, I'd like to convert `usize` into `Vec<u8>`

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from making your own trait?

Comment: Couple gotchas here: (1) you actually would want to use `From` and flip the types and (2) an implementation like this needs to be either where `usize`, `Vec<u8>`, or `From` is defined. Your options are to: make a new wrapper type or make a new trait.

Comment: As the other commenters have said; this is deliberately disallowed in Rust. You either need to wrap one of the values in a type that you own **or** implement your own trait. You will then own the trait or the type, and will be allowed to implement a trait for it.